# When using Ajax with PHP, which of the following are necessary to verify success?

Tags: php, ajax, http-status-codes, http-response-codes

Which of the following answers are correct ?

- HTTP ready state of TRUE
- HTTP ready state of 4
- HTTP status code < 400
- HTTP status of 200
- Data present in the response

Comment: Define "success".

Comment: read this : http://www.yaldex.com/wAjax/DiggingdeeperintoHTTPreadystates.html

Comment: ALSO : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both HTTP status of 200 and HTTP ready state of TRUE

Answer (score 0):

In all my apps, I require only `ready state 4` for success, which means as little as: the request is done and the response (if any) is available.

But like Madmartigan very wisely commented: define your version of success.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, an HTTP ready state of 4 and HTTP status code of 200 is needed in order to guarantee that data has been successfully transferred back to your program.